# как сделать условие в шаблоне pdomenu для конкретного ресурса

Tags: modx, pdotools

Как сделать условие в шаблоне pdomenu для конкретного ресурса с id 124 например.

```
&tplInnerRow=`@INLINE [[+id:is=`124`:then=`<li class="footer__list-item"><a href="[[+link]]" class="footer__list-link" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`:else=`Нет`]]`
```

Comment: А что в вашем коде не работает? только в else добавить вариант для других ресурсов например else=` `Нет[[+wrapper]]` `

Comment: @Tunker, проблема рендера у меня, могли бы вы посмотреть https://modx.ru/vopros-otvet/info/8818/?

Answer (score 0):

если проблема рендеринга(а значит синтаксиса?!), попробуйте не использовать INLINE,а поместить код в чанк, т.е.

> yourChunkTpl:

```
[[+id:is=`124`:then=`<li class="footer__list-item"><a href="[[+link]]" class="footer__list-link" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`:else=`Нет`]]`
```

а в сниппете так:

> &tplInnerRow=``yourChunkTpl`\`

Еще я видел случай, когда `is` не работал, а `isequalto` - да. Какая версия MODX? проверьте ради интереса другой модификатор также.